# templated method in a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

If I setup the following template method of a template class `foo:func`

```
template<typename T>
class foo{
  public:
    template<typename U> static void func(){}
};

int main(){
  foo<int>::func<long>();
}
```

everything works fine. When I try to call `foo::func` from a template class

```
template<typename T>
class foo{
  public:
  template<typename U>
  static void func(){}
};

template<typename T,typename U>
class bar{
  public:
    bar(){
      foo<T>::func<U>();
    }
};

int main(){
  bar<int,long> b;
  foo<int>::func<long>();
}
```

I get the following compile error:

```
main.cpp: In constructor ‘bar<T, U>::bar()’:
main.cpp:13:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
     foo<T>::func<U>();
                   ^
main.cpp:13:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
     foo<T>::func<U>();
                     ^
```

How can I call `foo::func` from the template class `bar`?

Comment: `foo<T>::template func<U>();`